# Check Constraint Referencing Unique Column on another Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys, constraints, check-constraints

I would like to limit the available values that can be entered in a column, but the values I would like to use are in another table, which is not the primary key of that table; the primary key of that table is not included in my table.

As an example, say I make a table for reporting of customers (Columns: Id, Name, Title) which references an existing table of customer titles (Columns: Id, Label) Both tables have primary keys on Id. I want the customers table to show the customer's title in words, not the title.Id associated with the customer. I know that the customer title column should only include values from the titles table. I cannot change the structure of the titles table.

Here are three options I have considered, but which I don't really like:

1.I cannot reference the title.label column with a foreign key as it is not a primary key.

2.I could create a check constraint and make a dynamic script to update it with the values in the titles table before updating the customers table with title labels, but this feels very hand cranked.

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(50) = 'Customers'
DECLARE @FieldName VARCHAR(50) = 'Title'
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + '
OR ' + @FieldName + ' = ''' + Label + ''''
FROM dbo.Titles
ORDER BY Label

SELECT @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE dbo.' + @TableName + ' DROP CONSTRAINT chk_Customer' + @FieldName + '
ALTER TABLE dbo.' + @TableName + ' ADD CONSTRAINT chk_Customer_' + @FieldName + ' CHECK
  (' + SUBSTRING(@SQL,6,LEN(@SQL)) + ')'

PRINT @SQL
```

3.I could just leave it be and forget about constraining the column at all, but I would rather add constraints where possible to keep everything battened down as much as possible and improve querying performance.

So, the question is this: is there a built-in way to reference one column (to limit or enumerate the values) by reference to another table, without having to script out the values in some way; something that once created will always be kept up to date, much as a foreign key relationship is but without the necessity to reference a primary key.

Comment: Put the `TitleId` in the `Customers` table and use a `join` to fetch the string value when you need it.  Don't start using foreign key references to non-primary keys, unless you have a really good reason -- and trying to save a join in this case is not a "really good reason".

Comment: I would rather do this as well and keep it all relational, but the table is used by so many reports as it is that changing things over would be a nightmare (and I'm not the only one who writes the reports). I have spoken to the report writers and they much rather have all the information they need in one very indexed table, at least for what they see as trivial bits like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, like GordonLinoff comments, the better approach is to include `TitleID` in the `Customer` table.  Below is an option if you can't change the layout of the `Customer` table.  A `foreign key` is definitely better than using dynamic T-SQL to keep a `check` constraint up to date.

> I cannot reference the title.label column with a foreign key as it is
>   not a primary key.

A foreign key can reference any candidate key.  It doesn't have to reference the primary key.

To tell the database about candidate keys, you can create a unique index:

```
create table title (
    id int primary key, 
    label varchar(50));
create table customer (
    id int primary key, 
    title varchar(50));
create unique index ux_title_label on title(label);
alter table customer add constraint fk_customer_title 
    foreign key (title) references title(label);
```

Another way to tell the database about a candidate key is a unique constraint:

```
alter table title add constraint uc_title_label unique (label);
```

Comment: Something new every day. Thanks, it sounds perfect; I'll give it a go.

Comment: Just curious, would it be any difference with a unique constraint on title(label), instead of a unique index? (NULL's perhaps?)

Comment: @jarlh [see msdn](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224827), index creation options other than FILLFACTOR that are available for a unique index are not available for a unique constraint